# Trying to Split One List into Multiple Lists Inside of a Main List - Python

Tags: python, string, list, iteration

For some reason I get this traceback when trying to split comma delimited items into a new list and then inserting them into a higher list:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "S:/Personal Folders/Andy/Python Projects/People Cancelled/Analyze Customers Test.py", line 15, in <module>
    text[x] = textnew
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Here is my code:

```
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

in_file = open("s:/Personal Folders/Andy/Python Projects/People Cancelled/Analyze Authorize Truncated.csv")
text = in_file.readlines()
in_file.close()

header = text[0:1]
text = text[1:]

for x in text:
    textnew = x.split(",")
    text[x] = textnew

print(text)
```

A sample of what data is being used:

```
['3545869260,59.95,AUTH_CAPTURE,Jack,Franklin,810-555-2222,jack@francypants.com,01-Apr-2011 05:24:10 PM PDT\n', '354589999,0,VOID,Jacob,Rasnip,8224309464,goodness@finland.com,01-Apr-2011 05:24:10 PM PDT\n']
```

I basically want to make each comma delimited piece of information INSIDE the list into a separate list, so basically a bunch of lists inside of one main list.

Thanks!

Comment: can you give a simple example with some input and the wanted output ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the information you need in the error message:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

You probably whant to do something like:

```
the_new_list = [x.split(',') for x in text]
```

Example:

```
>>> text = [
... '3545869260,59.95,AUTH_CAPTURE,Jack,Franklin,810-555-2222,jack@francypants.com,01-Apr-2011 05:24:10 PM PDT\n',
... '354589999,0,VOID,Jacob,Rasnip,8224309464,goodness@finland.com,01-Apr-2011 05:24:10 PM PDT\n']
>>> the_new_list = [x.split(',') for x in text]
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(the_new_list)
[['3545869260',
  '59.95',
  'AUTH_CAPTURE',
  'Jack',
  'Franklin',
  '810-555-2222',
  'jack@francypants.com',
  '01-Apr-2011 05:24:10 PM PDT\n'],
 ['354589999',
  '0',
  'VOID',
  'Jacob',
  'Rasnip',
  '8224309464',
  'goodness@finland.com',
  '01-Apr-2011 05:24:10 PM PDT\n']]
>>>
```

Answer (score 4):

this...

```
for x in text:
    textnew = x.split(",")
    text[x] = textnew
```

should probably be this...

```
for index, line in enumerate(text):
    text[index] = line.split(',')
```

The problem in the first example is that you are using `x` as an index into `text`, but text is an array of strings, so `x` is always a string, and using a string as an array index as `text[x]` raises an error, because array indices must be integers. My example corrects this by enumerating `text` - which returns not online the string as `line` but the number of the line as `index`. Hope that makes sense; I suggest playing around with it until you get it.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
result = []
for x in text:
    textnew = x.split(",")
    result.append(textnew)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
>>>>a = '3545869260,59.95,AUTH_CAPTURE,Jack,Franklin,810-555-2222,jack@francypants.com,01-Apr-2011 05:24:10 PM PDT\n', '354589999,0,VOID,Jacob,Rasnip,8224309464,goodness@finland.com,01-Apr-2011 05:24:10 PM PDT\n'
>>>for b in a:
    for x in b.split(','):
        c.append([x])    

>>> c
[['3545869260'], ['59.95'], ['AUTH_CAPTURE'], ['Jack'], ['Franklin'], ['810-555-2222'], ['jack@francypants.com'], ['01-Apr-2011 05:24:10 PM PDT\n'], ['354589999'], ['0'], ['VOID'], ['Jacob'], ['Rasnip'], ['8224309464'], ['goodness@finland.com'], ['01-Apr-2011 05:24:10 PM PDT\n']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, its only one line and it should get what you want done.

```
[[x] for x in open('test.csv').read().split(',')]
```

Just switch out `'test.csv'`  for whatever your csv file is.

Or, in three lines if you prefer:

```
a = open('test.csv').read()
[[x] for x in a.split(',')]
a.close()
```